# How can I change django default logout success template?

Tags: django, django-authentication

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oc0km.png)

by default its showing admin logout page.

I tried

```
path('logout/',auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='registration/logged_out.html'), name='logout'),
```

this is not working

Comment: Do you see any errors?

Answer (score 1):

Hey so django offers a setting where you can change the default logout redirect url.

First you need to make a view: (in views.py)

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class logout_page(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'logout.html'
```

Then add the url for the view:

```
path('logout/', views.logout_page.as_view(), name='logout-page'),
```

Then add this in your settings.py

```
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'logout-page'
```

This will change the default logout redirect.

Answer (score 1):

Put the application containing your 'registration/logged_out.html' first in your INSTALLED_APPS.

The idea is that Django should address that template before the one defined the Django admin app. This may be what you are looking for.